# How to implement scattered chart using chart.js which is not available by default?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I need to implement the scattered graph / chart using Chart.js ... By default I am not able to implement it as there is no function defined for the chart type of "Scattered" ... Can anyone help me with implementing the scattered graph using chart.js ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Scatter chart extension](http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/) that is linked to from the community extension section in the [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-community-extensions)